# How to do ssh and scp from linux server to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, ssh, scp

I want to understand how can we do ssh and scp from linux server to windows server. Can we simply run ssh and scp command like below from linux server.

1. ssh user@IPaddressWindowsserver
2. scp /home/ubuntu/myfile username@IP_of_windows_machine:/C:/Users/Anshul/Desktop.

I also want to execute these commands from jenkins pipeline script, I am using windows as my node in jenkins.

Can I simply run like below using bat script.

bat 'ssh user@IPaddressWindowsserver'
bat 'scp /home/ubuntu/myfile username@IP_of_windows_machine:/C:/Users/Anshul/Desktop'

Note:- I want to do ssh from linux to windows only, not the other way round.

Comment: You would need an SSH service running on the WIndows server. For example, an instance of OpenSSH on Windows Server 2019 or Windows 10, or something like Bitvise SSH Server (which is only free for personal use) on anything from Windows XP SP3 or Windows Server 2003 onwards.

Comment: Okay Ian. Thanks for your reply. Also wanted to ask if I can do scp from linux to windows server. And If I can run these commands of jenkins file like below.

bat 'ssh user@IPaddressWindowsserver'
bat 'scp /home/ubuntu/myfile username@IP_of_windows_machine:/C:/Users/Anshul/Desktop'

Comment: scp, sftp and ssh are supported. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1437891) for OpenSSH on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019, the remote paths are as you described. For Bitvise SSH server, I do not think drive letters are used, and it is possible to configure different root directories and mount points for different accounts.

Comment: Okay, thanks Ian for the answer. I will definitely give a try to it.

Comment: I have wsl installed. Found my ip address by `ifconfig` . how to now find the username which i can use like user@ipaddress